# How do we add a spell in Skyrim with the Creation Kit that can spawn several variants of the same NPC?

Tags: skyrim-modding

I am thinking of adding a spell that can summon a Nord, but I want it to have a random chance of spawning a female nord. I also want the NPC to appear in different armors, have different tattoos and different hairstyles. Is it possible to do this without using a script? What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have a function that is able to create new reference objects of any base object selected. The edits you talk about, character attributes, are usually manually adjusted, but there once was a mod that did loop through a list of prevously defined colours of wolf's fur to spawn differently looking enemies randomly. This mod did require SKSE.

So you would have to prepare different base objects and then call them via script and spawn them, following your own rule. Perhaps on activate event, similar as a magic effect.
The mod that could work as a proof of concept for your idea is
"Automatic Variants" - but it requires manual preparation of these encounters.
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/21377?tab=description

I am not sure how to access the actor properties via script and adjust them inside the script without GUI - i guess that would require much more work, to have variables randomly change these properties.

best success